# Use a server for chat backup like Telegram or WhatsApp

Tags: node.js, mongodb, server, chat, backup

I'm adding a chat on my app with node js server, I'll save a cache to my local storage using MongoDB realm but I know that I've to put a limit on doing saving data inside my phone, just some megabytes, that's why I'm thinking to create a backup on another server, right now is on digitalocean but saving all the data there could be expensive thinking about images and videos and of course, being optimistic...
Could you please recommend an option? I was thinking about using AWS Glaciar but I'm very open to other options, thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For videos, image, etc. Amazon S3 is one of the main choices. It also come with a great node API to connect to your S3.

Comment: Wow, I used AWS 2 years ago but I didn't know that now is so cheap, thank you for your help!!!